# Telnet with ipaddress and port in Python

Tags: windows, python-3.6, telnetlib

I need to login into remote server with IP address and Port.

```
import telnetlib

try:
    conn = telnetlib.Telnet("IPaddress", "Port")
    response = 'Success'
except:
    response = 'Failed'
finally:
    print(response)
```

Connection is getting success. But while trying to see the configuration of the server using the below command, getting error message.

```
print(conn.read_all())
```

> Welcome to xxx version: 3.2.28.38
>
> Built: 20/10-2016 at 14:56
>
> Unauthorized access prohibited
>
> uclibc login:
>
> Login timed out after 60 seconds.

Comment: It seems pretty obvious from the output that the device is prompting you for a username/password, and you're not providing it. What is your actual question here?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Here the issue is, it is not allowing me to give login details, login timeout happens before the user providing input.

Answer (score 1):

this also works for me:

```
import socket

def isOpen(ip , port):
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  try:
    s.connect((ip , int(port)))
    s.shutdown(2)
    return True
  except:
    return False
```